# SQL Server Dynamic Query Issue with GEOMETRY value - 'POINT' is not a recognized built in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

I am building a stored procedure for SQL Server 2014. All works as expected except I receive an error when trying to use a geometry type to base the location results upon.

```
USE UKStreetsAndPlaces
GO

DECLARE @Latitude Decimal(9,6) = 51.3083162
DECLARE @Longitude Decimal(9,6) = -0.7799193
DECLARE @LongitudeOperator AS NVARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @CentrePoint GEOMETRY
DECLARE @BoundarySize int = 20
DECLARE @HowMany int = 25
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500) = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@HowMany AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ' ([Name] + '', '' + ISNULL([Settlement],'''') + '', '' + ISNULL([Cou_Unit],'''') + '', '' + ISNULL([Postcode],'''')) As [Address] FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator]'

SET @LongitudeOperator = '-'
-- CREATE a Geometry type from the supplied Latitude and Longitude so we can return results around a certain area 
SET @CentrePoint = GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(@Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326);

IF (@Longitude < 0)
    -- Negative, turn to a positive number
    BEGIN
        SET @Longitude = ABS(@Longitude)
        SET @LongitudeOperator = '+';
    END

SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' WHERE Name LIKE ''pol%'''
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND ([Centre].STDistance(' + @CentrePoint.ToString() + ') <= (' + CAST(@BoundarySize AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ' * 1609))'
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' ORDER BY (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(@Longitude AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ') * (Longitude ' + @LongitudeOperator + ' ' + CAST(@Longitude AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ')'
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' + (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ') * (Latitude - ' + CAST(@Latitude AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ') ASC'
PRINT @SQLQuery
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

If I comment out the 'SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND ([Centre]....' line the query works fine but when I include it I receive the error:

'POINT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

The actual executable string looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 25 ([Name] + ', ' + ISNULL([Settlement],'') + ', ' + ISNULL([Cou_Unit],'') + ', ' + ISNULL([Postcode],'')) As [Address] FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] WHERE Name LIKE 'pol%' AND ([Centre].STDistance(POINT (51.308316 -0.779919)) <= (20 * 1609)) ORDER BY (Longitude + 0.779919) * (Longitude + 0.779919) + (Latitude - 51.308316) * (Latitude - 51.308316) ASC
```

Comment: doesn't POINT have to be surrounded in single quotes?  ie `[Centr].STDistance('POINT (51.308316 -0.779919)')`?

Comment: That certainly stops the error but the query no longer returns any results when I know there should be many: I now have: "WHERE Name LIKE 'pol%' AND ([Centre].STDistance('POINT (51.308316 -0.779919)') <= (20 * 1609))"... Perhaps this part of the query is crafted incorrectly?

Comment: Greg, as your suggestion did solve the issue, if you post it as an answer I can accept. I will post a new issue around the query itself not returning results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting quotes around POINT should resolve the error.  ie:

```
[Centr].STDistance('POINT (51.308316 -0.779919)')
```

As for not getting correct results back, I would add the schema and some sample data so we can take a look.

Comment: Great. Perfect. This answers the immediate question but I now have a new one relating to the query itself not returning results. I'll post a different question  for this.